# Threads causing CPU problems

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm trying to use multi-threading in VB. I have a program which is scanning a very large shared area (200k+ files) and performing a number checks on each file. I have created 10 threads each running the same function but with a different parameter. The parameter which I pass to the function is the high level directory path which the function will start at and dig down through. My logic is that splitting the function over smaller directories will be quicker than running it once over one big directory. However this is using 100% cpu and I'm sure there's a way I can save processing power from switching between threads ect but everything I've search for online hasn't really helped. Below is where I've created and started by threads:

```
        Dim TempAreaThread As Thread = New Thread(Sub() Tempchecker(tempDir))
        Dim MainAreaThread1 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() MainChecker(dir1))
        Dim MainAreaThread2 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() MainChecker(dir2))
        Dim MainAreaThread3 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() MainChecker(dir3))
        Dim MainAreaThread4 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() MainChecker(dir4))
        Dim MainAreaThread5 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() MainChecker(dir5))
        Dim MainAreaThread6 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() MainChecker(dir6))
        Dim MainAreaThread7 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() MainChecker(dir7))
        Dim MainAreaThread8 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() MainChecker(dir8))
        Dim MainAreaThread9 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() MainChecker(dir9))

        MainAreaThread1.Start()
        MainAreaThread2.Start()
        MainAreaThread3.Start()
        MainAreaThread4.Start()
        MainAreaThread5.Start()
        MainAreaThread6.Start()
        MainAreaThread7.Start()
        MainAreaThread8.Start()
        MainAreaThread9.Start()

        TempAreaThread.Start()

        TempAreaThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
        MainAreaThread6.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
        MainAreaThread8.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction for using the threads more efficiently that'd be great as my 4 cores are struggling. I'm a student so I understand that this may be a very naïve question and that my use of threads is appalling.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can try with a `Parallel.ForEach`...there is an example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: What's `MainChecker()` doing?

Comment: @Malcor it's a method that steps through each file in a directory, checks if they were last edited more than 60 days ago, are temporary files ect. It then finds any subdirectories and dives into them and repeats the checks.

Comment: MainChecker() also prints to the console, so could it be slowed due to competing for console use?

Comment: For efficiency, you need two thread. One that open/read files and one that parse the data. If you read two files at the same time, the needle on the harddrive will go all over the place and will slow down the process.

Comment: Depending on your needs, using the [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383504(v=vs.110).aspx) may be more efficient for processing the files.  You indicate a 60 days since last modification criteria. The FileSystemInfo instances returned from this method provide the LastWriteTime property for checking that.  As @the_lotus has indicated, you do not what to be thrashing the disk access.  Perhaps you could build a list of files for further action after the scan completes, but that all depends on what your end game is.